# How to implement Salesforce oAuth2.0 in a windows service

Tags: c#-4.0, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I have to implement a windows service which will uses salesforce oauth2.0 for authentication.

As per the flow, first we call authorization URL, it will redirect the user to login page. Its okay for web application, user can login using browser and after login it redirects to the callback url with token and other details in url and we can write code on redirected page to get the token etc for further use but how to handle it in a windows service running on a server?

Please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to handle this scenario for my windows service. Flow will be the same as explained in the question.

On callback url we get some details from REST API like token, refresh token etc. We can store this information in the database table and our windows service can use this token from database to fetch the data from salesforce resources. If the session get expired, we can use refresh token to get new session. In this way user will only have to login salesforce once and there after windows service will take care.